# Process.Start occurred error when dont allow to make change to this pc for unknown publisher

Tags: c#

i write wpf application that can checks for update on my host,
if update is available,it downloads new files and when download completed i start another console application with Process.Start and close my wpf app ,
in my console application ,all downloaded files will replace with orginal files
my problem: when i start my console app with Process.Start in my wpf app,windows show a dialog to confirm allow app to make changes to pc for unknown publisher,if user click no button, an error exception occurred,how can i manage exception?
bellow is my code in wpf app:
(updaterApp.exe is my console app)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("UpdaterApp.exe");
this.Close();
```

Comment: `how can i manage exception` [Try/Catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtd0s8kd(v=vs.110).aspx) is a good place to start. It would be even better if you told us what exception you're actually getting.

Comment: is there a way to avoid display this confirm dialog?

Comment: Not really. It's built into Windows to make the user aware that he or she is about to run a potentially unsafe application.

Answer (score 0):

There should be several workarounds to make this work properly; however, they will depend on the circumstances.

Will this application only run on your machine?

Will this application be deployed to multiple devices along with the application that is stated to be by an unknown publisher?

The easiest thing to do in this case would be to right click on the application "UpdaterApp.exe" and select properties. Under the general tab there will be an option at the very bottom saying to unblock the application. If you select unblock it should suppress this prompt from coming up anymore. Just be aware that this will only affect the application on your machine. If it needs to be deployed to multiple devices, as long as you make that selection before deployment you should be just fine.